# Look back and stop on the first one

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to solve this problem with a regular expression :

```
1A2TestB
```

Retrieve what's between 2 and B knowing that B is fixed and known, 2 is the first digit backwards which should give me Test

Is there a simple way (a secret symbol) to do this?

I thought I could do it with the Lookbehind

```
(?<=\d)(.*?)B
```

but no matter how hard I try, I can't get what I want.

Comment: Maybe `(?<=\d)\D*?(?=B)`? Or, `\D*?(?=B)`.

Comment: You can use `(\D*)B` where `\D` matches any non-digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\D*?(?=B)
```

Or, to avoid empty results:

```
\D+?(?=B)
```

**Details**

- `\D*?` - 0 or more chars other than digits, as few as possible
- `\D+?` - 1 or more chars other than digits, as few as possible
- `(?=B)` - a position in the string that is immediately followed with `B`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8wSEC/1)